# Render HTML tags in C#

Tags: c#, html, wpf, rendering

Is there an easy-to-use library or otherwise method in which I can pass HTML as a string (with tags like < table > or < div > etc) and then the application will show it correctly on the screen?

So far I have only found HTML Agility Pack, but it doesn't seem very noob friendly.

An Example:

```
submitted by <a href="http://www.reddit.com/user/kiransran"> kiransran </a> 
to <a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/news/"> news</a> 
<br/> 
<a href="http://imgur.com/GtDN6rz">[link]</a> 
<a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/news/comments/1cretq/infrared_image_of_boston_marathon_suspect_hiding/">[976 comments]</a>
```

It's from an RSS Feed. I need to show the result in WPF

Comment: This question isn't particularly clear.  What are you trying to do exactly with the HTML string?

Comment: @Ek0nomik Parse it, so that it doesn't appear as text, but appears as on a website.

Comment: @Vipar: Render or parse?

Comment: @Blender Not 100 % of the difference, but it sounds more like Rendering, rather than parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to render it, use the web browser control:

```
<WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="203" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="335" Margin="46,52,0,0" Name="wb1"/>
```

Then call the NavigateToString method:

```
string s = @"<html><body>Hello <b>World</b></body></html>";
wb1.NavigateToString(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string manipulations to extract the html of interest start & finish, wrap it and display it with a browser control:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rahul4_saxena/webbrowser-control-in-wpf/

The string manipulation API is something that you are going to learn anyhow, and if you just want to display the HTML, then you just need to provide the browser control with the suitable html.

You may need a WebRequest to fetch the RSS in the first place, but you haven't asked about that.

Comment: I got the RSS Request thing down. My application fetch the feeds. But it seems I am looking for rendering, rather than parsing.

Comment: That is what the browser control does. RSS is XML, so you only need to parse out the content and maybe the title. Since you don't really care about the XML, you can use ordinary substring searching to find the parts you care about. (Or you could load it into an XML doc, it depends on what API you want to use. If you don't want to use AgilityPack, I imagine you don't want to use the XML libraries either)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Geckofx:

http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/

However if you want you can use the Webbrowser control, but remember that is just IE.